# Get Apache configuration from PHP script

Tags: php, apache

Particularly I need to know `ErrorLog` Apache configuration setting from PHP script to show the latest fatal errors.

Can PHP obtain such setting or I need to pass the log path manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Apache will not reveal that information to PHP, even if it runs as Apache module. You have two possibilities:

- If you control the server, you can enable the [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_info.html) Apache module. It generates an HTML page that looks like this:

  ```
  In file: C:/Archivos de programa/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/sitios.d/foo.conf
     4: <VirtualHost *:80>
     5:   ServerName foo
     7:   DocumentRoot "C:/Sites/Foo/htdocs"
     9:   ErrorLog logs/foo-error.log
    12:   <Directory "C:/Sites/Foo/htdocs">
    13:     AllowOverride All
    14:     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      :   </Directory>
      : </VirtualHost>
  ```

  Of course, if you control the server you can simply inspect the `*.conf` files yourself.
- You can always configure PHP to send its errors to a known location (I'd say this is the most common approach). You can use the [error_log](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) and [log_errors](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) PHP directives.

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not have a built-in command for locating the apache error log.  As an alternative, you could do something like this in the apache config.

```
ErrorLog /var/log/apache/error_log
SetEnv APACHE_ERROR_LOG /var/log/apache/error_log
PassEnv APACHE_ERROR_LOG
```

In your PHP script $_SERVER['APACHE_ERROR_LOG'] should be what you are asking for.

Comment: But when I tried line 'PassEnv APACHE_ERROR_LOG',       PassEnv variable APACHE_ERROR_LOG was undefined

Comment: just setting SetEnv worked, no need for PassEnv as it gives a warning when reloading apache http://davetayls.me/blog/2012/01/04/set-custom-environment-variables-apache-php/

Answer (score 3):

To get Apache configuration You can setup `mod_info` module. Look at [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_info.html).
You get Apache configuration at link: http://localhost/server-info. [**Here**](http://www.apache.org/servinfo) live example.

```
<Location /server-info>
    SetHandler server-info
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

To get this info in php You could use:

```
<?php
    echo(file_get_contents('http://localhost/server-info'));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks the only approach for this issue.

Comment: The 'live' example (http://www.apache.org/servinfo) returns a Not Found.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

This will give you every part of php configuration

I'm not sure you can get apache configuration though

Comment: Didn't find the Apache log path. If PHP would be configured to write the logs inside it's own log, it would be simple though.

Comment: I have got APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

Comment: Thanks, but still this is not enough. You can set any file using the ErrorLog directive.